# iMacros - this TAG is failing (not finding the input field)

Tags: windows, firefox, imacros, data-extraction

Here's the input field I'm trying to select (from the website)

```
<input class="inputtext" maxlength="100" aria-label="Search" 
placeholder="Search Your Friends" autocomplete="off" 
aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns=
"typeahead_list_u_jsonp_6_3" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" 
value="Search" type="text">
```

I need to TAG it, and then do a relative search for URLs to extract after it. (I don't need to put anything in the input field.) The TAG is failing, and I'm getting the 1st URL on the page, not the first one after the input field.  (The above entry field is the only easily selectable item before the links I need to grab.)

Here's the code that fails:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:*  
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF
```

iMacros v. 7.6.0.2 for Firefox
Windows XP SP3

(Unfortunately, the iMacros official forum is dead.  So I brought this here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only TAG things that you can do something with, such as forms, fields, and links.
See: http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG

Answer (score 0):

that is because your code is to generic, try:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=class:inputtext
```

Comment: For some reason that isn't working.  Go to any facebook friends list page (yours or any other one).  The tag isn't found, there's that delay, and then the next tag also fails, extracting #EANF#.
If you comment out the first tag line, and change POS=R1 to POS=1 in the 2nd line, the first link on page the is correctly extracted.

Comment: There's one other unique thing I could search for before the friends links, and that's "'S FRIENDS."  Just the "'S."  The problem is, I can't find in the documentation how to tag an apostrophe.

Comment: The links are all after the input search box.  There's a link for every friend.

Comment: If you are asking for a link to a page with a friends list, you'd have to be logged in to see it. And if you are logged in, you can just go to your own.